# Nested DataWindow needs dynamic sort on a particular report object

Tags: powerbuilder

How can we sort dynamically in nested DataWindow on particular report object?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve your problem. First of all If you have a composite DataWindow (with more DataWindow inside it), you have to get the "child" DataWindow first (which is one of the DataWindow inside your composite DataWindow). After you got this reference, you are able to sort it like a normal DataWindow. Let's say that you have a composite DataWindow with the name: dw_report

```
long    ll_ret  = -7
string  ls_sort
DataWindowChild dwc_child

dw_report.GetChild("myChildDW", dwc_child)

dwc_child.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
dwc_child.Retrieve()

ls_sort = "Column1 ASC"
ll_ret  = dwc_child.SetSort(ls_sort)
ll_ret  = dwc_child.Sort()
```

Let see it in details:

long    ll_ret  = -7
string  ls_sort
DataWindowChild dwc_child

here you get the reference to the child. It is importantant, myChildDW is the name of the child DataWindow NOT the Report name or dataobject

```
dw_report.GetChild("myChildDW", dwc_child)
```

If you have already retrieved the data this 2 rows are not necessary

```
dwc_child.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
dwc_child.Retrieve()
```

Let's assume that you have a column name: Column1 and you would like to sort it ascending

```
ls_sort = "Column1 ASC"
ll_ret  = dwc_child.SetSort(ls_sort)
ll_ret  = dwc_child.Sort()
```

I hope this helps :) Have a nice day!

Br. Gábor